# What food is best for a 2 month old kitten that has been abandoned by its mother?

Tags: cats, diet

What's the recommended kitten food? How often should I feed it? (It's a kitten abandoned by its mother after 2 months.) I give it milk around every 4 hours and twice a day give it minced meatballs. Is this sufficient (considering its age of about 2 and a half months old), or should I add something more to it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would avoid giving cows milk as there is a good chance the kitten will be lactose intolerant. Stick to kitten/cat milk such as [Whiskas Kitten Milk](https://www.whiskas.co.uk/our-products/cat-milk) or goats milk in a pinch. The meat balls might not be the best - if they are intended for human consumption then it may contain higher levels of salt than is healthy for a kitten and may be lacking in nutrients that they need. The odd "treat" of human food isn't really a problem but it shouldn't form the main bulk of the diet.

At two months old a kitten should be eating kitten-tailored cat food as it is generally more calorific then adult food to support growth. something like [Royal Canin Kitten](https://www.royalcanin.co.uk/products/cat/feline-health-nutrition-wet/kitten-instinctive/)  or W[hiskas Kitten wet](https://www.whiskas.co.uk/our-products/wet-food/whiskas-kitten-poultry-selection-in-gravy-12-x-100g) (the Royal Canin is higher quality but does cost more). You could also try giving some dry food such as [Well Beloved Kitten dry](https://www.wellbeloved.com/product/turkey-kitten/).

These are examples and obviously there is a wide range of brands and flavors that exist - it should be labeled for kittens (they may describe it as being for cats under 12 months old) and ideally you want it to be described as "complete" - this means that it will provide all the nutrients that the kitten needs.

Comment: I had to stop kitten food and start adult food since my cat was 5 months old. By mistake I had once given her adult food. After that she always begged for adult food and not eat kitten food if given.

Comment: @Sonevol I wouldn't worry about it.. while kitten food is *better* for them it won't do any real harm for them to have adult food. It's not like they have kitten-specific prey in the wild :)

Comment: @motosubatsu Tell that to my feet while I'm trying to sleep.

Comment: @motosubatsu,Can curds be an alternative for it? From Meat balls I meant, raw minced meat.Also It ate a cockroach, will it affect her?

Comment: @MueezSiraj not sure about curds to be honest, they should be relatively low in lactose but I can't say I've ever tried feeding them to cats so can't say.  Raw minced meat shouldn't be too bad (assuming no added ingredients)  but it probably doesn't fully satisfy a kittens nutritional needs. In of itself a cockroach isn't harmful to the kitten - although there are possible complications if the 'roach has ingested poison I suppose. I'd call it a good sign.. cats love hunting bugs generally.

Comment: Meatballs also commonly include mixed up onion and other flavourings which are harmful to felines

Answer (score 6):

At 2 months old your kitten can already digest solid foods.

After weaning (that is, when they no longer get milk from their mother's teat), most mammals, including kittens lose the ability to properly digest milk (specifically lactose).

If you really want to give it something that looks and (sort-of) tastes like milk, go for the special kitty milk, which is not made of kitties, but rather from milk with reduced lactose content.

Answer (score 1):

I give my one and a halfmonth old kitten Royal Canin paediatrics weaning. It was recommended by her vet because my kitten did not want to drink kitty milk at all. I saw a real difference in her, I highly recommend.

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, thanks for posting, optimally answers should be a bit more elaborate, please read [answer] and consider adding some more information, thanks.